# Concurrent synchronization, avoiding key violations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple databases that are kept in sync using a log table:

```
source bigint,
tick serial,
data text

primary key (source, tick)
```

So the naive synchronization approach is for example on my second source synchronizing data from the first source:

```
insert into log_table (source, tick, data)
select source, tick, data
from other_db.log_table
where source = 1
and tick > (select max(tick) from log_table where source = 1)
```

I've simplified the example. In practice it is using dblink to query the other database but I don't believe that is relevant to this issue. The problem I hit is that if I have multiple threads synchronizing I get key violations.

My current though is to detect a key violation and simply retry. It is likely that this retry will not process anything as the other thread will have done the work. I'm wondering if there might be a more efficient approach though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use postgres 9.6 or greater you can try upsert statement `on duplicate key do nothing` (or `on duplicate key do update` depends on what you want to do)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html

with your query

```
insert into log_table (source, tick, data)
select source, tick, data
    from other_db.log_table
    where source = 1
        and tick > (select max(tick) from log_table where source = 1)
on duplicate key do nothing
```

Or you can try to use stored procedure in which you will be able to use row level locks
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/explicit-locking.html

For example, you can create a function that will look smth like this

```
create or replace function tick_update() returns void
language plpgsql as
$f$
declare
  max_tick integer;
begin
    select max(tick) into max_tick from log_table where source = 1;
    for rec in 
        select source, tick, data
        from other_db.log_table
        where source = 1
            and tick > max_tick
        for update
    loop
    insert into log_table (source, tick, data) values (rec.source, rec.tick, rec.data)
    end loop;
end
$f$
```

Comment: Nice, ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING is exactly what I want.
I think your second example though would still attempt to insert the same records multiple times as the for update locks are done on the other_db after the max tick has been obtained.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forget about `for update skip locked` in the second example